# ASP.NET MVC: Referencing a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I am setting up a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project in Visual Studio. My project is called `MyProject`. I have a model called `MyModel`, and a controller called `MyController`:

```
\\ MyModel.cs

namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }
}

\\ MyController.cs

using MyProject.Models;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MyModel my_model;
            return View(my_model);
        }
    }
}
```

However, in `MyController.cs`, I get the error message: `The type or namespace 'MyModel' could not be found.` Why is this? I have already included `using MyProject.Models;`, so shouldn't this be sufficient?

Thanks!

Comment: close and re open VS and Rebuild your project and see what happens. Also if the Models are in a different asssembly, Make sure to add relevant "References"

Comment: Restarting/rebuilding doesn't help. But I have noticed something else now. If I try to create a `MyModel` object in the default `AccountViewModels.cs` file, it also says that it cannot find `MyModel`. However, if I try to create a `LoginViewModel` object (found in the default `AccountViewModels.cs` file) in the `MyModel.cs` file, this works fine. Now, when I first added MyModel, I got the error: `You are attempting to add a special file type (class) to an ASP.Net Web site. In general, to use this type of item in your site, you should place it in the App_Code folder...`. What's all this about?

Answer (score 0):

using MyProject.Models; should indeed be sufficient. Have you tried Rebuilding the solution (not build!) and restarting visual studio? My VS2013 needs a restart from time to time as well if I have been messing around with too many references.

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly receiving the error within your view? Try adding the namespace to the appropriate section within the `web.config` file found under your views folder.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <add namespace="MyProject.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```